# In Corda, how do I configure my node's H2 username and password?

Tags: corda

My Corda node defaults to using "sa" as the username and "" as the password for the node's H2 database.

How do I configure my node to change the username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following section to your node's configuration file:

```
dataSourceProperties : { 
    "dataSource.user" : myNewUsername 
    "dataSource.password" : myNewPassword
}
```

You can also configure your data source class name and data source URL:

```
dataSourceProperties : { 
    dataSourceClassName : org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
    "dataSource.url" : "jdbc:h2:file:"${baseDirectory}"/persistence"
    ...
}
```